# Can javax.crypto.Cipher return different results for different providers?

Tags: java, encryption

When retrieving instance of `javax.crypto.Cipher` you may request a particular provider or let the system to choose one:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" /*, here may be Provider parameter*/);
```

Is it **guaranteed** that omitting of the provider parameter will work always and message encrypted on one system can be decrypted on another?
Or, in other words, are providers responsible only for implementation and text encrypted by provider A can be always decrypted by provider B?

Comment: I think the default values for mode of operation/padding are not standardized, but omitting them is a bad idea anyways.

Comment: Each cipher name that is fully qualified should yield the same output, because everything is standardized. But bugs happen and you can't be really sure. If it is not fully qualified (e.g. `"AES"`), then the provider uses its own defaults as CodesInChaos said. I don't know if this question can be answered correctly.

Comment: Sorry, my question isn't about mode and padding. Only about providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [standard algorithm names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html), so the code will always work. If another provider, that has a higher priority than a standard provider, implements the same algorithms, then this provider is selected. But the provider does not matter here.

AES encryption in [CBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) with PKCS#5 padding only then produces the same result if the parameter **IV** (initialization vector) is the same.

You can either pass an IV to the init method or let the provider generate a random IV for you:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey); // random IV
```

You can query the random IV by calling getIV():

```
byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
```

Provided that you know the IV, you can decrypt the result with every JCE provider that implements AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding or even in another programming language (e.g. C with openssl). That's the point of crypto standards.

Comment: Interesting to note that the iv + encrypted data needs to be passed over to the decrypting program.
Only if the length of init vector[IV] and the secret key is known both to encrypting and decrypting programs will this mechanism be successful.

Just adding a few pointers for a better picture.

Answer (score 0):

In  [Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Design) by Oracle is said:

> Implementation interoperability means that various implementations can
>   work with each other, use each other's keys, or verify each other's
>   signatures. This would mean, for example, that for the same
>   algorithms, a key generated by one provider would be usable by
>   another, and a signature generated by one provider would be verifiable
>   by another

So **result for different providers should match**. 
Still as @Artjom B. mentioned bugs may happen.